# Probability of two teams matching up in semi-finals of 32-team knockout tournament.

Tags: probability, combinatorics, conditional-probability

There are 32 teams in a traditional knockout tournament. Each of these 32 teams are of a different quality and can be distinctly ranked from 1st to 32nd in terms of ability. Assume that a higher-ability team always beats a lower-ability team. The teams are randomly seeded in the schedule of this knockout tournament. What is the probability that the second-best team meets the third best team in the semi-finals?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Because of the existence of the 1 seed, the 2 and 3 seeds can't meet in the final.  Therefore, necessary and sufficient is that the 2 and 3 seeds are in the same group of 16, the 1 seed is in the other group of 16, and the 2 and 3 seeds are in different groups of 8.

Comment: So, in that case, would it make sense to say that the probability is (16/31) - the probability that the 2 seed is in a different group than the first, multiplied by (8/30) - the probability that the 3 seed is in a different group than the 2 seed and the 1 seed?

Comment: $\frac{16}{31} \times \frac{8}{30}$ : correct.

Answer (score 0):

To explain Lourran answer's . Imagine an array of 32 numbers from 1 to 32 randomly distributed, such that one of two neighbour numbers proceed to next round based on their ranking.

The rank 1 can be in 32/32 places. The rank 2 cannot be in the same half as 1 (else they will meet before or in the semi finals) so it has 16/31 choices. The rank 3 cannot be in same quarter as rank 2 and cant be in same half as 1, so 8/30 choices. SO the answer is 32/32 * 16/31 * 8/30